# Jade Mixin for List

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I'm trying to create a jade mixin where I can input the number of items in a list.

Example,

```
mixin list(n, text)
    .list
        a(href="#") #{text}
        a(href="#") #{text}
        .....n times
```

If I call the mixin like this

```
+list(4, 'hello')
```

the outputted html should resemble:

```
<div class="list">
    <a href="#">hello</a>
    <a href="#">hello</a>
    <a href="#">hello</a>
    <a href="#">hello</a>  
</div>
```

How could I achieve this (with a loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution with two mixins, one for the loop, the other just for the text, you can also do it in one mixin.

```
mixin nlist(n, text)
  each i in Array(n)
    +list(text)

mixin list(text)
  a(href="#") #{text}

+nlist(4, "hello")
```

Comment: Thank you very much..that mixin is very handy.
I found a similar one.but not useful for very long lists.

mixin buttonlist(...items)
 each item in items
  a(href="#")= item

+buttonlist('link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4')

Comment: Another Variation..
mixin nlist(classname, n, text)
 ul(class='list-'+classname)
  each i in Array(n)
   +list(text)
+nlist('simple', 4, "hello")